# Is there a tool to automatically pack individual textures into one big png?

Tags: textures, tools, texture-atlas

I<s>'m currently</s> was working on a texture pack for [minecraft](http://www.minecraft.net) (but this question is not restricted to that). All terrain textures are squared and stored in one big terrain.png. (FYI that's from [Glimmar's Steampunk pack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?t=48884)). I'd like to store each texture in an individual file and have same automated process pack them into the terrain.png later on (maybe leaving the not yet created ones their default). At the moment I do this manually by copy/pasting them with gimp (at least the raster helps a lot here) but I'd really like to do this automatically. Basically this seems to be what happens behind the scenes of the [Painterly pack customizer](http://painterlypack.net/customizer.php) already. So,

> Is there a tool that replaces some <s>squares</s>polygons<sup>*</sup> in a png file with new ones (also png), the position of which might be configured in a separate file?

**edit** Some automated resizing for different resolution versions might be nice as well...

**edit2** Meanwhile I learned that "position [...] configured in a separate file" means atlas, and since the question originated from Minecraft texture packs (IIRC the format got changed meanwhile), the ideal tool would allow for using an existing atlas to replace some of the tiles

---

<sup>*)</sup> might as well ask the general case

Answer (score 4):

My favorite spritesheet packer is Texture Packer: http://www.texturepacker.com/

There's a free version that works pretty well, but the paid version adds features like resizing.

Another option is Zwoptex: http://zwoptexapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Nick Gravelyn's Sprite Sheet Packer](https://github.com/nickgravelyn/SpriteSheetPacker). I don't know if you can control scale with it, but you can easily automate that in script with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

Comment: Unfortunately, ImageMagick will only pack sprites if they are all the same size...

Comment: I should have clarified and mentioned that I intended ImageMagick to be a pre- and post- packer tool. The idea would be to do any per-sprite pre-scaling with ImageMagick, run Sprite Sheet Packer, and then run ImageMagick again on teh final results to shrink the output to your desired size if necessary.

Comment: the packer looks nice for writing my own game (so +1) since it outputs the dynamically calculated sprite positions, but since they are already defined by Notch, I need a tool to pack in customizable positions

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [crunch](https://github.com/ChevyRay/crunch) which is a free open source cli tool originally designed for [Celeste](http://www.celestegame.com)

Comment: Looks good, thanks. Is there any way to reuse an existing atlas?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by reusing an atlas?

Comment: I mean given an existing atlas from a previous crunching, is it possible to reuse that atlas so that the updated textures will be in the same place again and not in some pseudo randomized positions?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but why would you need to? The data should be defined in the atlas file (json/xml) so having sprites on different positions shouldn't be a problem.

In fact, it's best to put it on new positions to ensure everything is placed on the best possible position in the new texture dimension (if it changes).

Comment: I agree, and it makes perfectly sense if your game properly reads the atlas. But in the case of (old versions of) Minecraft, the atlas is (or at least was) hard-coded, therefore my question.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Unfortunately I don't think crunch supports that use case.

Comment: I was afraid so. It's still a good suggestion, so thanks again