# Stitch a collection of images into a tileset

Tags: tiles

I have a number of tiles as standalone files that I would like to stitch together into a single tileset. Are there any tools that can quickly do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a tool to automatically pack individual textures into one big png?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11673/is-there-a-tool-to-automatically-pack-individual-textures-into-one-big-png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Texture Packer. http://www.texturepacker.com/

Answer (score 3):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) has a useful append command that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

use http://slick.cokeandcode.com/demos/packer.jnlp.