# .PNG tiles to .PNG map

Tags: tiles, maps

I was wondering how I can get my 110+ .png map tiles conveniently into a 1:1 pixel ratio size map .png. I've been scrolling through Google and forums for the free ware game that I am modding, but the app I'm using recognizes only .png files, and I want more than 1% of the map. If you guys know of a program I would be very appreciative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a tool to automatically pack individual textures into one big png?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11673/is-there-a-tool-to-automatically-pack-individual-textures-into-one-big-png)

Comment: I'd probably roll my own, as that doesn't sound too complicated, and I could add any features I wanted. stb_image, for instance, is a free library that supports both loading and saving of pngs easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such as [this](http://www.texturepacker.com/sprite-sheet-maker/) (free license for bloggers and framework developers) or [this](https://github.com/nickgravelyn/SpriteSheetPacker) (completely free but a bit less flexible)?

Comment: D:< I spend 2 whole days looking for something and you just whip it out minutes after I ask? Don't get me wrong I am very grateful, but wow!

Comment: The second will be more useful since I can edit the length and width with text. Thanks, you saved me time, sleep and headaches ;).

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :) Finding stuff online is usually easy as long as you know what to search for. In this case I knew immediately that I needed some sort of *texture packer* or *spritesheet maker* so...

Answer (score 6):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) with it's [convert -append](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#append) can also be used for this. Though, it only does appending into one direction, but if your tiles are named ascending (f.e. tile001.png) it can still be used in a loop:

```
convert tile00*.png +append line1.png
convert tile01*.png +append line2.png
convert line*.png -append wholeImage.png
```

As pointed out by [bummzack](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/20/bummzack), [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) will work also good.

```
montage tile*.png -geometry +0+0 wholeImage.png
```

Comment: You could also use ImageMagicks *montage* command. [As described here](http://www.bensnider.com/imagemagick-split-and-join-a-sprite-sheet.html).

Comment: @bummzack: Thanks, I'm not sure how I missed that. As an informational note only, [that site has a very poor rating, I'm not sure why](http://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/bensnider.com).

Comment: never heard of that WOT reputation thing. The procedure outlined in the blog post works fine though. I have used it myself in multiple occasions.

Comment: +1 for using montage. I've used that many times to make sprites from individual frames. Very handy.